# Does Wasabi Wallet 2.0 have coin control?

Tags: wasabi-wallet, coin-control

Can users select coin(s) while sending bitcoin with Wasabi Wallet 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **No**

Long answer: Coin control is removed in Wasabi Wallet 2. Users can no longer select coins for a transaction. They would only see some labels associated with clusters.

*Note*: *Everyone can see all bitcoin transactions as they are public*.

Rationale provided by developers for removing it: https://github.com/zkSNACKs/WalletWasabi/discussions/7255

[image: no-coin-control]

I had answered this in an email which was censored by moderators of bitcoin dev mailing list. It was in response to misleading things shared in https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/bitcoin-dev/2022-March/020032.html

Answer (score 3):

Wasabi Wallet 2.0 DOES NOT have coin control. That being said it DOES HAVE privacy control that's an improved version of coin control. This is still mandatory when the user does not have enough coinjoined coins to make the transaction from.

The idea of privacy control rests on the analysis of how the user uses coin control today. Based on what he selects his UTXOs? It's based on the labels. Labels in Wasabi are entities those may know about a transaction or a specific UTXO belonging to the user.

Furthermore blockchain analysis heuristics cluster together UTXOs, which makes it more fruitful if the users select clusters instead of individual UTXOs.

Privacy control compared to coin control reduces the cognitive load of the user, thus leaving room for fewer mistakes.

Furthermore if someone would still like to see his coins, he can use this super secret developer key combination to do so: `CTRL + D + C`.

Comment: It's not an improved version of coin control. User is not aware of coins and related properties when doing a transaction. You are making decisions for users, they can't express selectively hence no privacy.

Comment: From strictly privacy point of view, users can express selectively on wallet cluster level instead of individual coin level: they have less room to make bad decisions or mistakes hence improved privacy.